# Best solution for create restaurant/bar menu application

Tags: android, tablet

My client wants have application in her restaurant. On every table will be tablet with android system. I want create application with menu (maybe on website) but I must protect application to not close. Or Clients run something else from device. Best for me is application on full screen with and can close after entering password.

Maybe is some ready-made solutions application. Now i haven't any ideas how start this project.
I will be grateful for tutorial, links or tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement own solution for this case, more information:
https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Or use 3rd party solution https://www.android-kiosk.com/

If you don't need app in google play, I recommend first solution.